# no such file or directory for .h file error in Qt after organizing project

Tags: c++, qt

consider that i have a main.cpp file in root which include "mainview.h" in it.
The mainview.h file is in root/View.
I have configured the .pro file(add View/mainview.h to HEADERS tag) but it still can't find mainview header in main.cpp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I import header files to a library in one of my header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262291/why-cant-i-import-header-files-to-a-library-in-one-of-my-header-files)

Answer (score 2):

If you do e.g.

```
#include "mainview.h"
```

then the preprocessor will look first in the same directory as the source file doing the `#include`, then it will look in the system directories. If you have a header file in a sub-directory then you need to specify that too:

```
#include "View/mainview.h"
```

Comment: hi, can you do me a favor and delete your comment ?

Comment: @danicheeta This isn't a comment but an *answer*, and why should I delete it? If it doesn't help you then it's okay to say so, and tell us *why* it doesn't help you. And edit your question [to be good](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And perhaps also read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ as well.

Comment: it did help me back then, but i was noob then and its obviously a silly question.
the reason for deleting is im getting downvote for this and losing rep

Comment: @danicheeta If you think others might be helped by this question and my answer, then consider *improving* your question, and maybe upvote or even accept my answer? Otherwise just delete your question.

Comment: deleting post is what i wish, thats why im asking you to delete it.

Comment: @danicheeta I shouldn't have to delete my answer for that. Have you *tried* deleting your question?

Comment: yes, it says i cant until it has comment
i need it to get out of asking limit